# How can I apply an alpha mask to an Android drawable?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-button, android-vectordrawable

In my application, I need to change the background color of a button in response to certain events. That works fine by setting creating a drawable, setting its paint and using that drawable as the button background:

```
    ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable(roundRectShape);
    drawable.getPaint().setColor(color);
    b.setBackground(drawable);
```

Now, I want to overlay an alpha mask onto that drawable, creating a "striped" button. Here's how it should look like for a blue and a black button (assuming white as the background color, but these sections should really be 100% transparent):

[image]

I made this alpha mask in Inkscape, and successfully imported it as a vector asset. I might need to convert it to a bitmap of sorts, but I'm not sure.

I've read a bunch of articles and SO questions mentioning PorterDuff matrices to apply, but haven't been able to translate these into solving my current problem.

Anyone know how to do this?

---

Here's another visualization, hopefully making things clearer. The background color of the parent view of the button is pale pink here, and the button border is outlined in red (but should really be invisible in the end product):

[image]

Comment: I don't quite follow your explanation. For clarity, can you produce an image of a button as it would appear on a device?

Comment: @Karakuri, I've added another example outlining the button border and making the background non-white. Does that help explain the desired outcome? It's still mocked up in Inkscape, as I've yet to figure out how to do this in Android :)

Comment: Just a thought, but it might be easier to create your own View subclass that takes a color and draws the 6 bars itself with a `Paint` object. One dirty little secret about Android Views: any view can be made clickable (so you don't actually need a `Button` ... unless you want the text there too, then maybe you do need a `Button`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured out how to do this, albeit not using an SVG - too many issues there.

First, I switched from using a `Button` to `ImageButton`. Then I applied the following style:

```
<style name="stripedButton">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">left</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@null</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:longClickable">true</item>
    <item name="layout_widthPercent">70%</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/fade_in_bars</item>
    <item name="android:tint">@color/RED</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <!-- Stretch image to fill entire button. -->
    <item name="android:scaleType">fitXY</item>
</style>
```

`fade_in_bars` is just the png version of the alpha mask shown in the original question. The color can be set in XML or programmatically using the `tint` attribute. I don't quite understand why I need to set the background to null, but it looks strange otherwise. Finally, setting the `scaleType` to fitXY is needed so that all the stripes are shown, regardless of the size of the button on a particular display.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

//This will help.

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.yourimage);

img.setAlpha(100);
```

//Transparent is between 0 and 255;
//If you want to use Bitmap

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResources(getResources(), R.drawable.yourimage);

img.setImageBitmap(b);

img.setAlpha(100);
```

Comment: Thanks Steven. I found a way to achieve the desired effect, just posted my answer. I'm afraid I couldn't quite follow your example.

Comment: It's okay. There are many ways to do it. So, grab the code that is helpful for you.